# OpenAPI generated axios typescript client with React

Tags: reactjs, axios, openapi, openapi-generator

I have the following problem. I am using axios with React for communication with my backend API.

This is how it is configured:

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});

export const setAuthorizationHeader = (token: string) => {
  if (token) {
    axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
  } else {
    delete axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"];
  }
};
```

The problem is that now I want to replace it with a client-generated by open-api:

```
export class BaseAPI {
    protected configuration: Configuration | undefined;

    constructor(configuration?: Configuration, protected basePath: string = BASE_PATH, protected axios: AxiosInstance = globalAxios) {
        if (configuration) {
            this.configuration = configuration;
            this.basePath = configuration.basePath || this.basePath;
        }
    }
};
```

```
export interface ConfigurationParameters {
    apiKey?: string | Promise<string> | ((name: string) => string) | ((name: string) => Promise<string>);
    username?: string;
    password?: string;
    accessToken?: string | Promise<string> | ((name?: string, scopes?: string[]) => string) | ((name?: string, scopes?: string[]) => Promise<string>);
    basePath?: string;
    baseOptions?: any;
    formDataCtor?: new () => any;
}

export class Configuration {
    /**
     * parameter for apiKey security
     * @param name security name
     * @memberof Configuration
     */
    apiKey?: string | Promise<string> | ((name: string) => string) | ((name: string) => Promise<string>);
    /**
     * parameter for basic security
     *
     * @type {string}
     * @memberof Configuration
     */
    username?: string;
    /**
     * parameter for basic security
     *
     * @type {string}
     * @memberof Configuration
     */
    password?: string;
    /**
     * parameter for oauth2 security
     * @param name security name
     * @param scopes oauth2 scope
     * @memberof Configuration
     */
    accessToken?: string | Promise<string> | ((name?: string, scopes?: string[]) => string) | ((name?: string, scopes?: string[]) => Promise<string>);
    /**
     * override base path
     *
     * @type {string}
     * @memberof Configuration
     */
    basePath?: string;
    /**
     * base options for axios calls
     *
     * @type {any}
     * @memberof Configuration
     */
    baseOptions?: any;
    /**
     * The FormData constructor that will be used to create multipart form data
     * requests. You can inject this here so that execution environments that
     * do not support the FormData class can still run the generated client.
     *
     * @type {new () => FormData}
     */
    formDataCtor?: new () => any;

    constructor(param: ConfigurationParameters = {}) {
        this.apiKey = param.apiKey;
        this.username = param.username;
        this.password = param.password;
        this.accessToken = param.accessToken;
        this.basePath = param.basePath;
        this.baseOptions = param.baseOptions;
        this.formDataCtor = param.formDataCtor;
    }
```

For me is not clear how I should set the JWT token once I obtain it, and be able to use it with every ControllerApi that extends BaseApi. My assumption is that I need to create axiosInstance using the BaseApi class, but what configuration should I pass to the constructor and will this overwrite the default configuration?